# Failed to create directory /var/root/iOSOpenDevPackages

Tags: ios

I have read a lot of articles, but still not resolved, who can help me
here is the problem I encountered with `iOSOpenDev` and I use `xcode5.0.1`

Preparing to run Xcode Build Phase...

```
Signing /Users/liu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedBoy-agqiwpedazizphbbdcgogvekvdya/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/SpeedBoy with ldid... 2014-02-19 12:39:50.818 xcodebuild[513:d0b] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XEP.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-02-19 12:39:50.824 xcodebuild[513:d0b] XcodeColors: load (v10.1)
2014-02-19 12:39:50.827 xcodebuild[513:d0b] XcodeColors: pluginDidLoad:
2014-02-19 12:39:50.855 xcodebuild[513:d0b] Could not fetch 'View' main menu item Done.
Copying /Users/liu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedBoy-agqiwpedazizphbbdcgogvekvdya/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/SpeedBoy to package directory at     /Users/liu/Desktop/SpeedBoy/SpeedBoy/Package/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/SpeedBoy.bundle...
Preparing to build package...
Setting control file /Users/liu/Desktop/SpeedBoy/SpeedBoy/Package/DEBIAN/control Version field to 1.0-1 using /Users/liu/Desktop/SpeedBoy/SpeedBoy/PackageVersion.plist... Done.
Building package ... Done.
Creating zip /Users/liu/Desktop/SpeedBoy/Packages/com.SpeedBoy_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.zip... Done.
Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Failed to create directory /var/root/iOSOpenDevPackages on device 192.168.88.146
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: Not sur exactly what you are trying to do but it seems you don't have write permission...?

Comment: I'm trying to develop jailbreak app, the final step "product -> build for -> profiling" encountered this problem. I can ssh to my iphone device but why not create directory

Comment: Oh, no idea. Don't deal with jailbreak.